# I can't run the created task with my bot on PythonAnyWhere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I have a project with a bot. Everything works on the local machine, if I run the bot through the terminal in pythonanywhere, then everything also works, but when I create a task and run it, errors appear

```
2023-04-29 11:09:30 - Task preparing to start
Apr 29 11:12:00 import-im6.q16: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/359.
Apr 29 11:12:00 import-im6.q16: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/359.
Apr 29 11:12:00 from: can't read /var/mail/time.check_time
Apr 29 11:12:00 from: can't read /var/mail/loader
Apr 29 11:12:00 import-im6.q16: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/359.
Apr 29 11:12:00 /home/I don't want to show my way/app.py: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Apr 29 11:12:00 /home/I don't want to show my way/app.py: line 9: `async def main():'
```

I repeat once again that the code is working and works perfectly on the local machine and through the pythonanywhere terminal

Comment: You need to share the command you are using and code it is running.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run code that uses async features in a version of Python that does not support async. Make sure you're using a Python version that supports async.